# Swift3: [String: AnyObject] using NSCoding protocol to save with NSUserDefaults

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults, nscoding

I have my custom class:

```
private class PendingRequest : NSObject, NSCoding
{
    var route : String!
    var params: [String: AnyObject]!

    init(route: String, params: [String: AnyObject])
    {
        self.route = route
        self.params = params
    }
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        self.route = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "route") as! String
        self.params = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "params") as! [String: AnyObject]
    }

    public func encode(with coder: NSCoder)
    {
        coder.encode(route, forKey: "route")
        coder.encode(params, forKey: "params")
    }
}
```

And here is how I save my list of `PendingRequest`:

```
private static func savePendingRequests(requestsToSend: [PendingRequest])
{
    let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: requestsToSend!)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: self.requestsToSendDefaultsString)
}
```

And here is how I try to retrieve it:

```
let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: requestsToSendDefaultsString)
let requests = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data!) as! [PendingRequest]
return requests
```

But my code crashes when retrieving my data... Saving works fine, but not retrieving... Any idea?

EDIT: Here is my `Crashlytics` error:

`*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: cannot decode object of class (_TtCC6Versus9VersusAPIP33_8D2B8AA415FDC4F8DFAF29D7ECE33C1F14PendingRequest) for key (NS.objects); the class may be defined in source code or a library that is not linked`

***SOLUTION:***

My class `PendingRequest` was `fileprivate`, thus `NSKeyedUnarchiver` couldn't access it, hence the crash... Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you please add crash log means error that is printing in debug console.

Comment: Consider that `AnyObject` has been changed to `Any` as the equivalent to Objective-C's `id`

Comment: @NiravD That's the thing, I have nothing printed in the console...

Comment: EDIT: Using Crashlytics, I managed to get some infos... Please, see my edit on the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Few things are incorrect

you're forgetting to call super.init() in your initializers

```
init(route: String, params: [String: AnyObject])
{
    self.route = route
    self.params = params
    super.init()
}
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
{
    self.route = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "route") as? String
    self.params = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "params") as? [String: AnyObject]


    // Check if route and params are what you expected here


    super.init()
}
```

You have a static method that calls "self", I'm not sure this works, you could still have a static key or a global key.
Plus you're unwrapping a non-optional value "requestsToSend".
I think this would solve it.

```
private static func savePendingRequests(requestsToSend:[PendingRequest])
{
     let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: requestsToSend)
     UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "AStaticKey")
}
```

Then retrieving should work. (I added a few safety checks)

```
guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "AStaticKey"), 
      let requests = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? [PendingRequest] else {
         return [PendingRequest]()
      }
return requests
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact, I forgot the `super.int()`. About the key, it is a static var (String). This didn't fix the problem though.